# Difference between three mutually complementary methods: Raman, Infra-red spectroscopy and inelastic incoherent neutron spectroscopy?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, spectroscopy, vibrations

When I read the wiki on [Raman spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy), I found a paragraph explaining what system is suitable for using Raman and what others do not. It provide two other method as shown in title: infrared spectroscopy and inelastic incoherent neutron spectroscopy. It says:

> A change in the molecular **electric dipole-electric polarizability** with
>   respect to the vibrational coordinate corresponding to the rovibronic
>   state is required for a molecule to exhibit a Raman effect. The
>   intensity of the Raman scattering is proportional to the electric
>   dipole-electric dipole polarizability change. The Raman spectra (Raman
>   scattering intensity as a function of the Stokes and anti-Stokes
>   frequency shifts) is dependent on the rovibronic (rotational and
>   vibrational energy levels of the ground electronic state) states of
>   the sample. This dependence on the **electric dipole-electric dipole
>   polarizability derivative** differs from infrared spectroscopy where the
>   interaction between the molecule and light is determined by the
>   **electric dipole moment derivative**, the so-called atomic polar tensor
>   (APT); **this contrasting feature allows one to analyze transitions that
>   might not be IR active via Raman spectroscopy, as exemplified by the
>   rule of mutual exclusion in centrosymmetric molecules**. Bands which
>   have large Raman intensities in many cases have weak infrared
>   intensities and vice versa. **For very symmetric molecules, certain
>   vibrations may be both infrared and Raman inactive (within the
>   harmonic approximation). In those instances, one can use a techniquie
>   inelastic incoherent neutron scattering to determine the vibrational
>   frequencies.** The selection rules for inelastic incoherent neutron
>   scattering (IINS) are different from those of both infrared and Raman
>   scattering. Hence the three types of vibrational spectroscopy are
>   complementary, all giving in theory the same frequency for a given
>   vibrational transion, but the relative intensities giving different
>   information due to the types of interaction between the molecule and
>   the electromagnetic radiation for infrared and Raman spectroscopy and
>   with the neutron beam for IINS.

I don't understand the terminology such as: **electric dipole-electric polarizability**, **electric dipole-electric dipole polarizability derivative ** and **electric dipole moment derivative**, and I don't understand the claim marked in bold either.

My question is as in the title: **How are these three method used as a complementary to each other?** What type of system is suitable for Raman (infra-red, neutron) and why?